# bootstrap modals works extremely slow on IE8 on windows vista

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, windows-vista

Inputs like textboxes and checkboxes work extremely slow in the bootstrap modals. When user types some text, cursor is moving but the letters appear only in several seconds. The same behavior with checkboxes, checked/unchecked state changes only in several seconds. 
Can be reproduced only IE8 and Vista machine. 
does anybody has an idea why it happens.

here is a [video](http://screencast.com/t/w3K1RkvO5Kn) with an example.
you can try it [here](https://photofeed.com) in the login dialog.

Comment: looks like too many repaints...but without viewing source its impossible to tell. i'll bet bootstrap is using incorrect + too many elements and ie8 can't handle the dom manipulation....

Comment: @albert, Thanks. You can look through the code, I updated the question

Comment: ok....still confused...i don't see any modals...do you mean that the form controls are slow in reacting?

Comment: @albert, try to open login modal(login link in the top left corner). It can be reproduced only in IE8 on Vista. Even winXP doesn't have problems with it.

Comment: ah...i see now. opacity and position:fixed, yay! try setting fixed to absolute in ie8. i bet you it has to do with positioning, even if that is not the easiest answer. it seems like its struggling mighty hard to catch up to the user...so i'm guessing repaints, etc.

Comment: @albert, thanks, you are right, it works much better with position: absolute, but it is default bootstrap style and I need fixed position of the dialog. So I have to make some special style for IE, as usual...hate this stuff.

Comment: well...i mean specifically setting the positioning to absolute in ie...i've done the dance you are doing before. it's tedious to say the least. you know how to target only ie's?

Comment: I changed position to absolute for all IE and not, to not support different design. It works fine with absolute and one hack in the bootstrap code

Comment: ...so you're good? if so, i'll write all this in an answer

Comment: @albert, yes sure, write it an answer and I will accept it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 100% why, but ie8 has extreme problems rendering sites using position:fixed in their layout process. on random element(s), position:fixed shouldn't be too much of a problem, but typically when this issue arises it is because it is being applied to elements that are used as wrappers or containers, that usually are full of content.
for whatever reason(s), ie8 has a mighty difficult time rendering here...its best described as delayed response(s), where the user isn't sure if they actually interacted with the site, because nothing happens after their action(s).
changing fixed to absolute is the best answer in these cases, most of the time. i know there are situations where this will not apply, but everytime i've faced this issue, the element(s) had wrapper element(s) with position:relative set, and swapping out absolute for fixed could not have been easier.
ideally for me, is to serve up the different setting in conditional comments, which also is quite useful just in case changing from fixed to absolute breaks something(s)...you can target them in ie(s) and ie(s) alone with the cc's.